# Importing multiple pictures into excel using VBA while keeping the picture ratio

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to import multiple pictures into excel at once -each in their own cell.  I have that set up and working well.  However I need to have the picture ratio stay the same so they fit within the cell, but do not come in looking "squaty" for lack of better terms.

This is my code that I have been using.  What do I need to add to make the picture ratio stay the same as pictures are sized to fit the cell.

```
Sub InsertPictures()
    'Update 20140513
    Dim PicList() As Variant
    Dim PicFormat As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim sShape As Shape
    On Error Resume Next
    PicList = Application.GetOpenFilename(PicFormat, MultiSelect:=True)
    xColIndex = Application.ActiveCell.Column
    If IsArray(PicList) Then
        xRowIndex = Application.ActiveCell.Row
        For lLoop = LBound(PicList) To UBound(PicList)
            Set Rng = Cells(xRowIndex, xColIndex)
            Set sShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(PicList(lLoop), msoFalse, msoCTrue, Rng.Left, Rng.Top, Rng.Width, Rng.Height)
            xRowIndex = xRowIndex + 2
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

This is what I have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```vb
Sub InsertPictures()
    Dim PicList() As Variant, c As Range, sShape As Shape, pth
    
    'ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects.Delete 'for testing
    
    PicList = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True)
    If IsArray(PicList) Then
        Set c = Selection.Cells(1) 'start at the selected cell
        For Each pth In PicList
            '  -1 means keep original dimension
            Set sShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(pth, msoFalse, _
                                    msoCTrue, c.Left, c.Top, -1, -1)
            'resize to cell width
            sShape.Width = c.Width
            'check the height...
            If sShape.Height > c.Height Then sShape.Height = c.Height
            
            Set c = c.Offset(2) '2 rows down
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is very close-except that it then just skips the pictures that don't fit...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that - what happens when a picture doesn't "fit"?  It doesn't import at all, or it imports but isn't resized?

Comment: A picture that is horizantal-taller than then the height of the cell, does not import, so just skips importing that picture.

Comment: If you step through the code does the import step not work at all?

Comment: Is there a way i can send you the spreadsheet with macro and the pics?  I am not sure how else to show/explain?   my email is brannn3@yahoo.com-if that makes easier?

Comment: I sent you a mail -check your Spam folder if it's not in your inbox.